# VDS SSH free -m - что показывает эта команда?

Tags: linux, vps, vds

Вот что мне показывает команда free -m

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           387        353         34          0         12        254
-/+ buffers/cache:         85        301
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Это получается что памяти всего 387 мб?

и может такое быть что показывает столько а памяти реально больше мне выделили в vds?

Comment: @KoVadim, наверно в тарифе было >512 :)

Comment: Нет на тарифе было 800 =)

Вообще при посещаловке 15000 юников сколько должно быть оперативки?

Comment: а кто его знает. кому то 640 кб хватит, а кому то пары сотен гигов будет маловато. а уники это дело такое. может их будет 15, но приходить они будут регулярно и надолго.

Answer (score 1):

> Это получается что памяти всего 387 мб?

да.

> и может такое быть что показывает столько а памяти реально больше мне выделили в vds?

нет.